# How to use draggable and resizable after drag & drop?

Tags: html, jquery, css, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/result.css?v=1.3" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<%@ page import = "java.io.*" %> 

<style>

html,body{
    width:100%;
    min-width:200px;
    height:100%;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}


ul,li{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

img {
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
}
img.menu {
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
width:90px;
height:90px; 
cursor:pointer;
}
.right_div{
    width: 90px;
    height: auto;
    float:right;
}
.center_div{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    float:right;
    right:90px;
}
.right_top{
    height: 90px;
    
}
.center_top{
    height: 90px;
    
}
.middle{
    top: 90px;
    height: auto;
    
}

.center_number,.center_alphabet,.center_korean {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    float:right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #ffffff;
}

#dropHere{
    width: Calc(100% - 500px - 90px);
    height: 100%;
    left:10px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border: dotted 1px black;}
    
    
    


.default_top {
    width: Calc(100% - 500px - 90px);
    height: 90px;
    left:10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #ffffff;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javaScript" >
$(function(){
    //Make every clone image unique.  
    var counts = [0];
    var resizeOpts = { 
    handles: "all" ,autoHide:true};    
    $(".dragImg").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        //Create counter
        start: function() { counts[0]++; }
    });  
    $("#dropHere").droppable({
        drop: function(e, ui){
            if(ui.draggable.hasClass("dragImg")) {
                $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
                $("#dropHere .dragImg").addClass("item-"+counts[0]);
                    
                $("#dropHere .item-"+counts[0]).removeClass("dragImg ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging");

                $(".item-"+counts[0]).dblclick(function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });     
                $(".item-"+counts[0]).draggable().resizable();   
            }

        }
    });


    var zIndex = 0;
    function make_draggable(elements)
    {   
        elements.draggable({
            containment:'parent',
            start:function(e,ui){ ui.helper.css('z-index',++zIndex); },
            stop:function(e,ui){
            }
        });
    }

        
});
</script>


<html>
<head>
<title>Graphic maker</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="right_div">
    <div class="right_top">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="image/test.PNG" width="90" height="90"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <ul>
          <li><img class="menu" src="image/app_icon.PNG" title="number"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
</div>


<div class="center_div">
    <div class="center_top">
        <input type="text" style="font-size:15pt; text-align:center; width:494px; height:85px;">    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="center_number">
            <%
            File path_number=new File("D://image//number");
            File[] fileList_number=path_number.listFiles();
            if(fileList_number.length>0){
                for(int i=0;i<fileList_number.length;i++){
                    String name=fileList_number[i].toString().substring(fileList_number[i].toString().lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
                    String fullname="image/number/"+fileList_number[i].toString().substring(fileList_number[i].toString().lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
                    %>
                    <img src=<%=fullname%> class="dragImg"
                    title=<%=name%>
                    width="90" height="90" >
                    
                    <%
                }
            }
            %>
        </div>
            
    </div>
</div>



<div class="default_top">
<script src="js/test.js" >
</script>
<h1>aaa</h1>
</div>

<div id="dropHere" ></div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

There is a script part at the top, jsp and Java code in the middle, and a div called dropHere is defined at the bottom. In the jsp implementation part, after taking one of several images returning to the loop and dropping it on `dropHere`, you want to make the dropped image draggable or resizable again.

But only resizing works. In my case, I drag & drop and bring it to the `dropHere` area and add that class. In this case, how do I add it as a div?

Or is there another way?

Comment: Why do you need all the indexes calculation? Every time an image start to dragged you increase the index? What about start but never dropped in `dropHere`? I'd suggest to declare the variable in the scope and refer the code to it: https://jsbin.com/rapesev/edit?js

Comment: I modified the code to full code.
You may have modified the code and the syntax may be incorrect.

The index increases because you drag & drop a image multiple times.
And I want to move or resize the dropped image in dropHere again.